# How to know variable/reference type in freemarker?

Tags: java, freemarker

How can i find type of any variable or reference used in ftl template in freemarker.
eg. if there is this code
`<#assign skuSize = productDetailResponse.simpleSkus/>`
How can I know what is type of `productDetailResponse` and `productDetailResponse.simpleSkus`?

Answer (score 0):

You mean the Java type of it. It's unusual in templates. On most configurations, and assuming those objects aren't Java types treated specially by FreeMarker (`String`, `Number`, `Boolean`, `Date`, `List`, `Map` and the like), `productDetailResponse.class` will call `getClass()` and so it works.